# React Native project does not start on the android emulator and no error is shown

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-vector-icons

I'm working on a React Native project (no Expo) end I'm using [react-native-vector-icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons)

Everything was fine until I updated the ttf file of my icons.  From that moment when I try to run my project on Android (with npx react-native run-android) build process is successful but application does not start on the emulator.

On iOS I have no problem.

Is there a way that allows me to understand what goes wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try to "Wipe Data" in the emulator before initialize your App.
You can do this in Android Studio, just follow the image:
[image: Android Studio Wipe Data]

If it doesn't work, you can go in your android folder with cmd ("cd android"), make a "./gradlew clean" there, then "cd ..", delete your "node_modules" folder, run "yarn install" or "npm install" and rebuild your project again with "npx react-native run-android".
Hope it works.

Comment: @react-native-community/cli-platform-android is having a problem(in the new version), if it accuses that you dont have the "android/app/build" folder after the "./gradlew clean", just run "./gradlew assembleDebug" in your "android" folder and everything shall be ok.

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply but I haven't solved my problem. I'm trying to run project 
on different  android devices but the result is always the same. 
What I don't understand is why it doesn't show any kind of error

Comment: i don't have the sufficient info to know exactly what your problem is, but if nothing worked, maybe its a node problem, have you tried to change your node version? what is the node version that you are using?

Comment: try one of the stable versions, maybe 10.14.1

Comment: you may have more info about your error running your app in debug mode.

Comment: I just tried to change node version but nothing has changed. How can I run my app in debug mode if it doesn't start on device?